# Use validation set to determine number epochs in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I was wondering whether it would be possible to use either cross validation or a fixed predefined validation set to determine the 'optimal' number of epochs for a NN using Keras in Python. 
I currently have the following code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 243))
# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 32, epochs = 20)
```

If it is possible, what would I have to add to the code? I realize it is not a replicable example, though I don't think it's necessary for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're totaly right! The best way to find "optimal" number of epoch is to use [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

That'll allow you to stop the training when you have reached the best score on your metric of interest.  Here’s an example

```
model = Sequential()
# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 243))
# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'mean_squared_error')

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=40) # Model stop training after 40 epoch where validation loss didnt decrease
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True) #You save model weight at the epoch where validation loss is minimal
train = model.fit((train_X, train_label, batch_size=batch_size),epochs=1000,verbose=1,validation_data=(valid_X, valid_label),callbacks=[es,mc])#you can run for 1000 epoch btw model will stop after 40 epoch without better validation loss
```

If you want to load your weight, I'll let you check on the internet how to do it. Saving weight allows you to re-use the model without having to train it again.

For the latter, note that following validation loss score is not always the best thing to do. One exercice for you could be to find how to save model when accuracy is at its maximum.

Comment: Thanks a lot akhetos! One more question: in the last line where you fit the model, does it finally combine the training and validation sets to compute the weights with the optimal epoch number? (in other words, does it refit based on complete data after having found optimal nr epochs?)

Comment: *es* and *mc* lines just allow you to define parameter for the callback function in the last line. If you run the code, when model stopped training, in python memory you'll have the weight for the epoch N+40 where N is the epoch which minimise validation loss. Be carefull I think  there are some parenthesis mistake in last line. **note** I'm not sure I have understand you'r question :/

Comment: I've implemented it now - is it normal that the validation loss keeps increasing from the first epoch onward? So the optimal epoch seems to be 1 every time?

Comment: that a strange behavior. Please if you are allowed give me more info about classification taks you want to solve and model architecture

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I understand your question completely or not, but if you want to add sth to your code, that decides how many epochs is enough to train your data, that's not possible. You should choose the number of epochs explicitly.
But other than that, you can use callbacks or TensorBoard. For example, choose your epochs to be 1000. Then you can use callbacks in a way that if the accuracy did not change stop the training. In general with callbacks, you can specify a condition, and when that condition occurs, do something else. (In our example if accuracy did not change after one epoch, stop the training).
Other than that you can use TensorBoard. With this tool, you can see the history of anything related to your model after the training.
Here is the link for callbacks and TensorBoard documentation: https://keras.io/callbacks/